# What is the difference between libdl and libltdl?

Tags: c, module, linker, libtool

What is the difference between `libdl` and [`libltdl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html). I just noticed that `libodbc` links to both of them

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2 | grep -i dl
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f411b822000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f411b01f000)
```

I know Perl links again `libdl`.

```
ldd /usr/bin/perl | grep -i dl
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55faa2e000)
```

I see two seperate shared objects on the system,

```
ls -lah /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.26.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 39K Aug 20  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15K Oct 11 15:21 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.26.so
```

They both link to similar stuff too,

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc3e66b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efcbad4c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efcba96c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efcbb15a000)
ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.26.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe7889c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbc9a14e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbc9a732000)
```

What makes `libltdl` different?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir what result are you seeing that address this?

Comment: One is part of glibc and the other is part of libtool.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: the `libltdl` page you linked to in the question answers your question: `libltdl` provides a portable dynamic linking interface. On Linux, it is a wrapper around `libdl`. If you run `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1` you'll see it requires `libdl`.

Comment: If that's all it is, just pop that over and I'll pick that answer. My bad, I probably should have see the `libdl` in the ldd of `libltdl` and though "wrapper" but it didn't occur =( @NominalAnimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of `libtool` to provide a `libdl` API (e.g. `dlopen`) for many different platforms that have the same or similar functionality (e.g. POSIX's `dlopen` etc., Windows's `LoadLibrary` etc.), and shared library emulation for platforms whose linkers don't support dynamic linking.

I did some analysis on `libodbc.so.2` on my Linux box.  `nm -D` seems to show only `libltdl` symbols for `libodbc.so.2`, and `objdump -p` seems to have only `libltdl.so.7` in the `NEEDED` section, so `ldd` doesn't seem to be printing out entirely accurate info in this case (Your `grep` output appears similar to what I see).